# Select $_POST through part of the $key

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a form that posts data to another php file.
A few keys are formed through day, date and the addition "-towards".

Table/Form:

```
                    <?php
                        for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++){

                            $d=strtotime("+".$i." Day");
                            if (date("l", $d) !== "Saturday" && date("l", $d) !== "Sunday" ){
                                $daydate = $dayOfWeek[date("l",$d)] .'_'. date("d", $d) .'_'.  $month[date("F",$d)];

                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td><strong>". $dayOfWeek[date("l",$d)] .' '. date("d", $d) .' '.  $month[date("F",$d)] . "</strong></td>";
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                echo "<td></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";

                                echo '<tr class="boardingTimeEarly">';
                                echo '<td style="padding-left: 30px; width: 24.5%; display: none">
                                        <input 
                                          class="form-check-input boardEarly1" 
                                          type="radio" 
                                          name="dates['.$daydate.'-to]" 
                                          value=""></input>
                                        <div class="time">0:00</div>
                                      </td>

                                    <td style="width: 24.5%; display: none">
                                        <input
                                          class="form-check-input boardEarly2" 
                                          type="radio" 
                                          name="dates['.$daydate.'-to]"
                                          value=""></input>
                                        <div class="time">0:00</div>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="width: 24.5%; display: none">
                                        <input 
                                          class="form-check-input boardEarly3" 
                                          type="radio" 
                                          name="dates['.$daydate.'-to]"
                                          value="">
                                        </input>
                                        <div class="time">0:00</div>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="width: 24.5%; display: none">
                                        <input 
                                          class="form-check-input boardEarly4" 
                                          type="radio" 
                                          name="dates['.$daydate.'-to]" 
                                          value="">
                                        </input>
                                        <div class="time">0:00</div>
                                    </td>   
                                </tr>';
                            }

                        }
                    ?>
            </table>
?>
```

I create the values of each input with JQUERY:

```
 $('#opstaphalte').change(function() { //OPTION IS SELECTED
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
url: 'reserve.php', 
dataType: 'JSON',
data: {
        'station': this.value 
    },

    success: function(response){
        var to = 0;

        if(response['to']){ //CHECK IF RESPONSE CONTAINS INFO
            to = 1;
        }           

        for (var j=0; j<4; j++){

            var tdInput = $('.boardingTimeEarly').find('.boardEarly'+(j + 1));
            var td = $('.boardEarly').find('td');

            //HIDE DIV AND INPUT
            td.css('width', 'auto');
            tdInput.css('display', 'none');

            //Make TD Visible after selection choice
            if(td.css('display') == "none"){
                td.css('display', 'table-cell');
            }

            //TO DESTINATION ------------------------
            if(to){
                if(response['to'][j]){  //show content according to amount of times (max:4)
                    td.css('width', '25%');
                    tdInput.css('display', 'inline-block');
                    tdInput.attr('value', response['to'][j].slice(0,5));    
                    tdInput.next().html(response['to'][j].slice(0,5));
                }
            }
            else{
                //No BOARDINGTIMES KNOWN
                td.css('width', 'auto');
                td.css('display', 'table-cell');
                var noTimes = $('.boardEarly').find('.opstapOchtend1');
                noTimes.next().html("No boardingtimes.");
            }

        }

    } //end SUCCESS

  }); // END AJAX
});
```

When I try to put all "towards" times selected in an array for POST.
I get "NUL".

**Vardump of my post**

```
array(5) {
 ["contact_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
 ["company"]=>
  string(0) ""
 ["email"]=>
  string(16) "test@gmail.com"
 ["boardingPlace"]=>
  string(1) "2"
 ["dates"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Considering my towards $_POST keys are dates that vary, how do I select them to put them in a mail?

How can I select the $_POST that have a date in in?
Do I search the $key for day and "towards" or "back"?

Or is there a better way??

Comment: Maybe change the form so all dates are in a dates array? `name="dates[Tuesday_03_july_towards]"` then you can get all in `$_POST['dates']`. Though your current array seems kinda clunky.

Comment: I changed it to name="dates['.$daydate.'-heen]" but after submit, the $_POST['dates'] is NULL.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can this be because I use JQuery and Ajax to set the values of these inputs after a 'station' is selected?